# Qual referencia importar para TableAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que a minha aplicação encontre a tag table.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Dominio
{
    [Table("Loja_Carrossel")]
    public class Carrossel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Nome { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
```

Lembre-se de ajustar seu Framework para a versão 4.5.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou.